# Hnadlebars property access denied in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebarshelper

I am getting an error:

> Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "status" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
> You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:

My code is like:

```js
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  deafultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials'
  }, {
    allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
    allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The view engine setup is correct. The problem is how you rendered your file.

**Case 1**

The `status` should be inside the parent object that is being sent.

Don't do this:

```
res.render('fileName', {data:status})
```

Do this instead:

```
const myObject = {status: your_data}
res.render('fileName', {myObject:myObject})
```

and do something like this in your handlebar file

```
<p>{{myObject.status}}</p>
```

**Case 2**

If you are trying the fetch data from MongoDB/Mongoose to display it in the front-end, then just add the .lean() method after .find()

```
const data = await ModelName.find({}).lean()
```

Comment: i really did not understand your comment. am  trying to display req.body in console. then I am getting this error. data is coming from a form. please help